# dc.js - dataTable -- combining data rows

Tags: javascript, datatable, dc.js

I am creating a dashboard, and the data format is as such:

```
var data = [
    {"id": 'CDE', "count": 1, "name": 'ajdkf', "type": 'E', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'CDE', "count": 0, "name": 'ajdkf', "type": 'E', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'CDE', "count": 0, "name": 'ajdkf', "type": 'E', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'CDE', "count": 0, "name": 'ajdkf', "type": 'E', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'HFG', "count": 1, "name": 'ajdkf', "type": 'E', "state": 'B'},
    {"id": 'HFG', "count": 0, "name": 'ajdkf', "type": 'E', "state": 'B'},
    {"id": 'HFG', "count": 0, "name": 'ajdkf', "type": 'E', "state": 'B'},
    {"id": 'HFG', "count": 0, "name": 'ajdkf', "type": 'E', "state": 'B'},
    {"id": 'ABF', "count": 1, "name": 'ghedw', "type": 'G', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'ABF', "count": 0, "name": 'ghedw', "type": 'G', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'ABF', "count": 0, "name": 'ghedw', "type": 'G', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'ABF', "count": 0, "name": 'ghedw', "type": 'G', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'DEF', "count": 1, "name": 'huiqs', "type": 'E', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'DEF', "count": 0, "name": 'huiqs', "type": 'E', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'DEF', "count": 0, "name": 'huiqs', "type": 'E', "state": 'A'},
    {"id": 'DEF', "count": 0, "name": 'huiqs', "type": 'E', "state": 'A'},
    ...
    {"id": 'ABC', "count": 1, "name": 'asbsd', "type": 'D', "state": 'B'},
    {"id": 'ABC', "count": 0, "name": 'asbsd', "type": 'D', "state": 'B'},
    {"id": 'ABC', "count": 0, "name": 'asbsd', "type": 'D', "state": 'B'},
    {"id": 'ABC', "count": 0, "name": 'asbsd', "type": 'D', "state": 'B'}
];
```

I am trying to create a table that looks like:

```
Name   State A Count   State B Count
ajdkf  1               1 
ghedw  1               0
huiqs  1               0 
asbsd  0               1
```

I currently have:

```
<body>
<div style='clear:both;'>
  <table id="Stats">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th> name </th>
            <th> State A Count </th>
            <th> State B Count </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
</body>

<script>
...
var dataTable = dc.dataTable("#Stats");
var dataTableDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.name;});
dataTable
    .dimension(dataTableDim)
    .group(function(d) {return d.name})
    .columns([
        function(d) { return d.name; },
        function(d) { if (d.state == 'A') {return +d.count;} else {return 0;} },
        function(d) { if (d.state == 'B') {return +d.count;} else {return 0;} },
    ]);
...
</script>
```

And it is giving me a table that looks like:

```
Name   State A Count   State B Count
asbsd
asbsd  0               1
asbsd  0               0
asbsd  0               0
asbsd  0               0
ajdkf
ajdkf  1               0
ajdkf  0               0 
ajdkf  0               0 
ajdkf  0               0
ajdkf  0               1 
ajdkf  0               0 
ajdkf  0               0 
ajdkf  0               0
huiqs 
huiqs  1               0 
huiqs  0               0 
huiqs  0               0 
huiqs  0               0 
ghedw
ghedw  0               0 
ghedw  1               0
ghedw  0               0
ghedw  0               0
```

What do I need to do to get the table that I desire?  I would love to have under "State A" 2 'columns' (Count and Percent) and the same for State B.  Something like:

```
Name        State A              State B
        Count     Percent    Count     Percent
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/56hgjgsz/14/

I couldn't get the fiddle to read external files, so I had to add them to the js.. sorry :(  (https://jsfiddle.net/56hgjgsz/29/)

This "works" but doesn't do the row reduction in the table and the ordering is backwards -> same address but with /32/ instead of /14/ or /29/

Comment: oof, the "external resources" section in jsfiddle is for pointing to d3 and dc, you don't need to include the source!

Comment: For some reason it wouldn't work :/  Sorry about that

Comment: It really slowed down the fiddle interface; that must have been really painful to work with! Also fixed in my updated answer below.

Comment: In your fiddle, the table only has one of the names initially instead of showing all of them.  It also doesn't update to include the others when choosing state B.  I added your solution below to my code and the table isn't removing "empty" lines.  I'm confused to why it's not working properly.

Comment: I changed the && to || and that fixed it :)

Comment: When .order(d3.descending), the values are Z-A order (as expected) on my code.  I would like them to be in ascending order.  When I try to do this in my code, I get "source_group.bottom is not a function".  Is there a way to display these in ascending order by name?

Comment: Not efficiently. But I've added a workaround below which should work (untested).

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of years after dc.js came out, people discovered that you can actually pass a **group** as the `.dimension()` for a data table. That's what you want here, since you are doing  crossfilter reductions to get the state counts.

[Here's an example.](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/table-on-aggregated-data.html) ([source](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/examples/table-on-aggregated-data.html))

This is [noted in the documentation here](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html).

The method for reducing multiple values in a crossfilter group is standard:

```
var dataTableGroup = dataTableDim.group().reduce(
  function(p, v) {
    ++p.number;
    p.total  += +v.count;
    p.stateA += (v.state === 'A' ? v.count : 0);
    p.stateB += (v.state === 'B' ? v.count : 0);
    return p;
  },
  function(p, v) {
    --p.number;
    p.total  -= +v.count;
    p.stateA -= (v.state === 'A' ? v.count : 0);
    p.stateB -= (v.state === 'B' ? v.count : 0);
    return p;
  },
  function() {
    return {
      number: 0,
      total:  0,
      stateA: 0,
      stateB: 0
    }
  }
);
```

Then we can make a "fake dimension" for the data table to read the top or bottom N values, keeping only bins that have a value for either `stateA` or `stateB`. Note we have to pass `N` through, unlike for fake groups:

```
function remove_empty_bins_dt(source_group) {
  return {
    top: function(N) {
      return source_group.top(N).filter(function(d) {
        return d.value.stateA !== 0 || d.value.stateB !== 0;
      });
    },
    bottom: function(N) { // hacky but should work 
      return source_group.top(Infinity).filter(function(d) {
        return d.value.stateA !== 0 || d.value.stateB !== 0;
      }).slice(-N).reverse();
    }

  };
}
```

Again, the data table is unique in dc.js in that it is designed to read data from a crossfilter dimension not a group. So we need to pass this fake dimension to `.dimension()` instead of `.group()` ([which means something completely different](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/855) sigh)

Working fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/d86foxyq/5/

(if I understood it correctly)

One could generalize this to look at an arbitrary number of fields, but I'm out of time for today.

Comment: How do I remove rows with zeros across the table?  When I click on a graph, I would like the table to update to show only those lines in the table.

Comment: You can [use a fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-empty-bins) to skip over the empty bins.

Comment: When I use remove_empty_bins() to create a new group to be used as my dimension (also when I want to sort the data ascending instead of descending), I am getting the error: "_chart.dimension(...).top is not a function".  Do you know why I am getting this error? And, how do I fix it?

Comment: Oh whoops, I forgot that the data table uses different methods to read data. I've added example code above. You may need to adjust if you are doing a custom reduce with multiple columns as shown in your question, but hopefully this gives the idea.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I'm getting "Invalid array length" error (crossfilter.js).  Why is this?  Also, when I change the sorting from descending to ascending, I get instead the error "source_group.bottom is not a function". :/  Any ideas?

Comment: Oh.... I guess `d3.ascending` is not going to work when using a group as a dimension (because it uses a heap sort) - you would have to reverse the order using [group.order](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_order). That's a good point and I'm glad you brought it up - I am working on the dc documentation right now.

Comment: I don't know about the "invalid array length" error - I can help you debug it if you post a fiddle or block.

Comment: I'll keep the link in the above description updated if I make changes to the jsfiddle.